# Using git filter-branch with Python subprocess module

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to write a script that will help me map some old users to new users in a handful of Git repositories.  The problem I'm having is with the subprocess module.  Simple commands like "git status" seem to work fine, but the more complex "git filter-branch" command is failing on me.

**filter_history function**

```
def filter_history(old, new, name, repoPath):

command = """ filter-branch --env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            cn="|name|"
            cm="|new|"
        fi
        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            an="|name|"
            am="|new|"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
    '
"""

#Do string replace
command = command.replace("|old|", old)
command = command.replace("|new|", new)
command = command.replace("|name|", name)

subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git', command], cwd=os.path.dirname(repoPath), shell=False)
```

Some example output:

```
fatal: cannot exec 'git- filter-branch --env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" == jacks* ]]
        then
            cn="Jack Slingerland"
            cm="jacks-teamddm"
        fi
        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" == jacks* ]]
        then
            an="Jack Slingerland"
            am="jacks-teamddm"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
    '
': File name too long
```

Some things I've noticed are that the git command is getting a hyphen appended to it, which doesn't make a ton of sense to me.  Also, if I remove the extra hypen from the command that is printed and execute it in repoPath, everything works fine.  Any help or direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you put a '`\`' at the end of each line of your `--env-filter` script? A bit like in the examples that you see in http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch. a `"""` isn't enough to warrant a multiline command when it come to the script part contained in that `--env-filter` parameter.

Comment: @VonC I changed the command to include back ticks after each line, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: backtick (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick)? I was thinking about backslash (\: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash), not backtick.

Comment: @VonC "Do as I think, not as I type."  Adding backslashes didn't help.  Instead it just made the command collapse onto one line, which bash wasn't fond of.

Comment: @Right... I should type comment while doing other tasks, sorry. I didn't see my initial comment. So since the issue remains, did you try other avenues? Like externalize the `--env-filter` parameter in an external script ? (And / or greatly simplify the script in order to see if the error message persists?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: (I am using linux)

```
def filter_history(old, new, name, repoPath):
    command = """'
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            cn="|name|"
            cm="|new|"
        fi
        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            an="|name|"
            am="|new|"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
    '
    """

#Do string replace
    command = command.replace("|old|", old)
    command = command.replace("|new|", new)
    command = command.replace("|name|", name)

    subprocess.Popen(['git filter-branch --env-filter', command],cwd=os.path.dirname(repoPath), shell=True)
```

Note that "shell=True" in subprocess.Popen function

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI for anyone that comes around, @xueyymusic was the closest.  I ended up using the following:

```
def filter_history(old, new, name, repoPath):

command = """--env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            cn="|name|"
            cm="|new|"
        fi

        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" == |old|* ]]
        then
            an="|name|"
            am="|new|"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
"""

#DO string replace
command = command.replace("|old|", old)
command = command.replace("|new|", new)
command = command.replace("|name|", name)

process = subprocess.Popen(['git filter-branch', command],cwd=os.path.dirname(repoPath), shell=True)
```